# What is the probability that both the designated captain and the vice captain will not be selected?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If a team of $12$ players is selected randomly from $18$ players, what is the probability that both the designated captain and the vice captain will **not** be selected.
$$1-\frac{12}{18}=\frac1{3}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: If one of the two is selected, is that included or not?

Answer (score 2):

$$P\left(\text{captain1 not selected and captain2 not selected}\right)=$$$$P\left(\text{captain1 not selected}\right)\times P\left(\text{captain2 not selected}\mid\text{captain1 not selected}\right)=$$$$\frac{6}{18}\times\frac{5}{17}$$